# javascript как правильно писать функцию в функции

Tags: javascript, валидация

Картина такая:

```
    var validation = $('#check').on('click', function() {

      function init() {


        function checkname() {
            var nameL = $("#name").val().length;
            var nameVal = $('#name').val();
            var regexp = /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇҐґ'][a-zA-Z-а-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇҐґ']+[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇҐґ']?\s[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇҐґ'][a-zA-Z-а-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇҐґ']+[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇҐґ']?$/;
            if (nameL === 0) {
                alert('Будь ласка введіть ім\'я та прізвище')
            } else if (nameVal.search(regexp)) {
                alert('перевірте ім\'я та прізвище')
            }
        }; //end func checkname

        return {
            checkname: checkname
        };

    }; // end func init

    return {
        init: init

    };

});
```

Это файлик, в котором я тренируюсь на кошках) функция чекнэйм, не завернутая во все остальные нормально работает. Вообще же их 3(чекнэйм чекмэйл чекпас)(знаю, алерты не тру, я их уберу позже). Я не понимаю как мне ретурном вывести эти функции наружу, чтобы они работали, т.е. по нажатии кнопки должно прочекаться 3 поля.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `.on` в качестве аргумента принимает функцию (т.н. `callback`), которая выполняется при срабатывании события (в данном случае при `click`).

Ретурном функции вывести наружу не получится, т.к. эта функция (`callback`) будет выполняться кодом `jQuery`, а туда доступа у вас нет.

Чтобы проверить 3 поля по нажатию на `#check`, можно сделать, например, так:

```
function checkname() {
  var nameL = $("#name").val().length;
  var nameVal = $('#name').val();
  var regexp = /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇҐґ'][a-zA-Z-а-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇҐґ']+[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇҐґ']?\s[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇҐґ'][a-zA-Z-а-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇҐґ']+[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇҐґ']?$/;
  if (nameL === 0) {
    alert('Будь ласка введіть ім\'я та прізвище')
  } else if (nameVal.search(regexp)) {
    alert('перевірте ім\'я та прізвище')
  }
}

function checkmail() {
  ...
}

function checkpass() {
  ...
}

$('#check').on('click', function() {
    checkname();
    checkmail();
    checkpass();
});
```

**UPD**

Если нужно, чтобы эти функции были изолированны от глобального пространства имён (или от какого-нибудь ещё), то самым простым способом будет их замкнуть в колбэке:

```
$('#check').on('click', function() {
    !function checkname() {...}(); //имя функции указывать необязательно
    (function checkmail() {...})(); //имя функции указывать необязательно
    (function checkpass() {...}()); //имя функции указывать необязательно
});
```

Другой вариант: создать объект, который будет содержать в себе эти 3 функции в качестве методов. При этом объект будет доступен **глобально**, а функции будут доступны только через этот объект:

```
var validation = {
    checkname: function() {...},
    checkmail: function() {...},
    checkpass: function() {...}
}

$('#check').on('click', function() {
    validation.checkname();
    validation.checkmail();
    validation.checkpass();
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать)